# Google sheets using condition formatting

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula

[image]I use Google sheets to track my son sleep pattern. I want to condition if he sleeps < 10 hours the duration in C2 will show in red color but if he sleeps >= 10 it shows in blue.

So far, I tried =C1>=TIME(10,0,0) and =C1*24>=10 but value in cell C always shows in red.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

*You may try with:*

```js
=timevalue(C1)>=10/24
```

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, the date is saved as the integral part of a real number, and the time is saved as the fractional part of that number.

You might think that the time value of 10:20 in cell C6 falls between the times 8:13 in cell B6 and 21:53 in cell J5. However, this is not the case. Since you entered the times 8:13 and 21:53 without any associated date, their integral parts default to 0. As a result, the 8:13 minus 21:53 represents a negative value when considered as a real number.

To understand this better, let's visualize it.

[image]

Next, we convert these cells to a number format.

[image]

Notice how the times are represented. To correctly compare only the time components without considering the dates, you should use the fractional part of the values. This can be achieved by using `MOD(value,1)` to ensure the values are between 0 and 1 (0 <= value < 1).

Therefore, to check if the time in cell C1 is on or after 10:00, the following formula can be used:

```
=MOD(C1,1)>=TIME(10,0,0)
```

This formula compares the fractional part of the time in C1 with the fractional value of 10:00, effectively checking the time irrespective of the date.

Also, in using the conditional format, you'd better use an absolute reference if possible. So

```
=MOD($C1,1)>=TIME(10,0,0)
```

would be better in your case where the column `C` is fixed.